# How to create input fields dynamicaly in vuejs (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am new to vuejs. I'd wanted to create input fields dynamically by the click of a button using vuetify. My attempt to implement is shown below and commented line wise to show what I was trying to achieve.
I there a way this can be done? Any suggestion is welcome.

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                <v-btn color="success">Add Input</v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="12" ref="mount">
                <!-- inputs fields are appended here -->
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                items: {},
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addField() {
                // create element
                let textField = document.createElement("v-text-field");
                // add it to the data property
                this.$data.items["firstName"] = "";
                // add the vmodel attribute to the element
                textField.setAttribute("v-model", "firstName");
                // finally mount it in the templates
                this.$refs.mount.appendChild(textField);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an array of objects like so `basic: [{ name: "", time: "" }]`. Then you can use a loop to bind inputfields to those properties and add items to that array. You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-nash-6v6jq?file=/src/App.vue:417-448)

```html
<div v-for="item in basic" :key="item.id">
    <button @click="addRow">Add row</button>
    <input type="text" v-model="item.name" />
    <input type="text" v-model="item.time" />
    {{ item.name }} - {{ item.time }}
</div>
```

```js
data () {
    return {
        id: 1,
        basic: [{ name: "", time: "" }]
    };
}
```

```js
addRow () {
    console.log("added");

    this.id += 1;
    this.basic.push({
        name: "",
        time: ""
    });
}
```